# Splitting paragraphs that begin as indents

Tags: python, csv, split

I have a long text that I need to split into paragraphs, then create a .csv that gives me a new paragraph per cell. Here is what I have tried:

```
paragraphs = str(chunks)
print (paragraphs)

Paragraphs1 = paragraphs.split("^\n\n")

data1 = zip(Paragraphs1)

with open('Paragraphs1.csv','wb') as f:
    w=csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['Paragraphs'])
    for row in data1:
        w.writerow(row)
```

This results in a .csv with two long rows of unparsed paragraphs. I have also tried using '\n' - it results in a new sentence per cell in the .csv, but the .csv keeps the paragraph structure. Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show us some output from that print statement or maybe some ideal I/O?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split()` does not take regular expressions. You are trying to split your text on literal `'^\n\n'` characters:

```
>>> 'Text with newlines\n\nand a caret at the end^\n\nwhich will be split'.split('^\n\n')
['Text with newlines\n\nand a caret at the end', 'which will be split']
```

If you wanted to use a regular expression to split on, use the `re` module:

```
import re

re.split(r'^\n\n', paragraphs, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

The `re.MULTILINE` flag ensures that `^` matches after every newline, not just at the start of the string.

Note that this assumes you want to split where there are **three** consecutive newlines. Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'^\n\n', 'Cool\n\n\nNew paragraph\nruns here\n\n\nAnother paragraph?', flags=re.MULTILINE)
['Cool\n', 'New paragraph\nruns here\n', 'Another paragraph?']
```

If two newlines are enough, use `$\n\n` instead:

```
>>> re.split(r'$\n\n', 'Cool\n\nNew paragraph\nruns here\n\nAnother paragraph?', flags=re.MULTILINE)
['Cool', 'New paragraph\nruns here', 'Another paragraph?']
```

Comment: Classic newbie mistake - thank you. How would I change it to take spaces after \n into account? Example: `'Thank you Mr. Chairman. I appreciate this \nopportunity.\n    Chairman Greenspan, it is a pleasure to welcome you here \nthis morning.`  where the \n after opportunity and before Chairman has a tab space. If I am remembering correctly, it's \s or something similar?

Comment: `\s` is all whitespace. `\t` is a tab character. `[\t ]` would be a tab *or* a space. `\s` would also match newlines, so that might not be what you want here.

Comment: So `Paragraphs1 = re.split(r'^\n\n\t', paragraphs, flags=re.MULTILINE)` or whatever permutation of \t,\s, or [\t] would be the structure? I'm clearly a beginner and just want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, but note that `^` itself is either at the start of the string or directly after a newline; this means `^\n\n\t` only matches at `'end of line.\n\n\n\tnew line with tab at start'`.